# Displaying multiple dataframes in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working on a problem, where I have to print results of some calculations and send them in email using R markdown.

There are several if else conditions in the code, (around 100) every time If Else condition is met, I want to print the generated data-frame in R markdown so that it can be part of email that I will send.

The overview of code looks like-

```
a <- 5
b <- 6

 if (a > b) {

      ## Print Data frame in R Markdown ##

    } else if (b < a)  {

       ## Print Data frame in R Markdown ##
    }}

## email the whole result Doc generated by R markdown ##
```

email part I am able to figure out, but I am not able to slice it down in chunks. every time my R markdown script is failed. any clue or path forward please.

Comment: There are several problems in your code: (I) the if-condition is in both cases the same, (II) the last `} ` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, I posted a comment, but this solution should work:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
a <- 5
b <- 6

 if (a > b) {

      knitr::kable(mtcars[,1:2])

    } else if (a < b)  {

      knitr::kable(mtcars[,3:4])
    }

## email the whole result Doc generated by R markdown ##
```
````

Comment: Thanks J_F, in fact I should thank you million times, this simple solution actually saved 2 persons job :)

Answer (score 2):

One trick I like to use in situations like this is to set the chunk parameters `echo` and `eval` by the conditional statements. Achieves the same result as J_F, but has broader applications.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
a <- 5
b <- 6
```

```{r chunk1, echo = a>b, eval = a>b}
knitr::kable(mtcars[,1:2]) 
```

```{r chunk2, echo = a<b, eval = a<b}
knitr::kable(mtcars[,3:4])
```
## email the whole result Doc generated by R markdown ##
```
````